# Creating Stored procedure within MySQL Workbench

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

Does anyone know how I can create a stored procedure within mysql workbench? I would like to get to know and use them but how do I store the one(s) I create so that I can then call them? In workbench or within my php code would be better.

**update** thought I might share this link as it might come in handy to anyone viewing this

[Stored Procedures in MySQL and PHP how to article](http://www.sitepoint.com/stored-procedures-mysql-php/?utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=SitePoint%20PHP%20Newsletter%20%2014%20January%202014&utm_content=SitePoint%20PHP%20Newsletter%20%2014%20January%202014%20CID_34a5290114a04b6d619cc4eb5efbae59&utm_source=CampaignMonitor%20SitePoint&utm_term=Stored%20Procedures%20in%20MySQL%20and%20PHP)

Comment: eggyal has the right sentiment but a poor choice of link.  We are talking about the application MySQL Workbench.  [Routines and MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-routines-routine-groups.html).  Begin reading here to see how MySQL Workbench handles stored procedures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

to add a stored procedure in Mysql workbench:

1) Click the triangle in the left of your database: you should see tables, views, and routines

2) Right click on routines -> Create procedure

You're done :)

Answer (score 1):

Within the EER diagram:

- Click the `Place a New Routine Group` toolbar icon, and
- Place the routine group.
- Double click the resulting rectangle to edit it.
- Go to the `Group: Routines` tab and
- Click the bottom `Routine Group` tab to edit the group or
- Click the bottom `Routines` tab to edit the actual routines.

Alternatively, from the Model diagram, click the `Add Group` icon under `Routine Groups` heading then click the `Add Routine` under the `Routines` heading.

[Source: dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-routines-routine-groups.html)